# Wireless RF wetness detecting alarm design

Tags: rf, conductivity

I am working on a project to trigger an alarm wirelessly using RF when wetness is detected. I'm using conductive threads to detect the wetness in a material through the principle of conductivity and then send the signal to a comparator to accordingly send it it to the 433MHz RF transmitter. I am just not sure whether I require an encoder between the comparator and the RF transmitter to convert it to serial data? What kind of data would output from the LM311 comparator into the transmitter? I am very new at RF so could someone please help me out with the circuit of this RF transmitter with the wetness sensor attached as conductive threads.

I wish to build this circuit with a kind of switch mechanism for the RF transmitter and receiver module avoiding the use of programming and Arduino. Any other design possibilities using the conductive threads?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Odd that you'd use threads. They have capillary action and it is difficult to "reset" the material for another "detection." So is that fine with you?

Comment: Resetting would be as simple as drying the fabric and placing it back for detection. This is for use on the body so sensor requires to be comfortable.

Comment: By 'difficult' I was thinking 'time consuming.' But you have constraints to work with. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: What RF module? It's like saying I want to use a "thing" so how will that "thing" perform. There is nothing generic about "433MHz RF transmitter"

Comment: you can find momentary-on rf modules that don't need modulation.

Comment: You could use LM311 output to switch on/off 433MHz RF transmitter (no modulation just single frequency oscillator). Use RF power detector IC as a receiver. Later add narrow filter after Rx antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do some coding on the RF signal because on/off only will be extremely difficult to detect reliably.

433 MHz devices generally tend to use [OOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying) which means an on/off pattern but with a certain timing and sequence. This is what garage door openers use.

The easiest way to perform this modulation and also the demodulation is by using a microcontroller, for example an Arduino. Almost any type of Arduino board will do.

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://arduinobasics.blogspot.nl/2014/06/433-mhz-rf-module-with-arduino-tutorial.html), there are libraries to use RF modules with Arduino making it quite easy to use.